# How can I get the onDownloadProgress percentage with axios get method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Here is my code :

```
React.useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos', {
                onDownloadProgress: (progressEvent) => {
                    let percentCompleted = Math.round(progressEvent.loaded * 100 / progressEvent.total);
                    console.log(progressEvent.lengthComputable);
                    console.log(percentCompleted);
                }
            })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log('response done');
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error.message);
            });
    }, []);
```

And this is the console.log :

```
false
Infinity
false
Infinity
response done
```

I get infinity while trying to get the get method progress event . How can I get the exact percentage for the axios get method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by using another api for get request . Simply the jsonplaceholder api doesn't have progress value for the get request .

```
axios.get('https://systran-systran-platform-for-language-processing-v1.p.rapidapi.com/translation/text/translate',
 { onDownloadProgress: (progressEvent) => {

     let percentCompleted = Math.round(progressEvent.loaded * 100 / 
     progressEvent.total);
     console.log(progressEvent.lengthComputable);
     console.log(percentCompleted);

  }
})
```

Comment: It would be a better Q&A if you showed the code on what exactly you did to solve your issue. May even get a few upvotes for it.

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ Edited the post and thanks for your comment .

Answer (score 2):

@Mehdi thanks for you question; I was having the same issue with getting `infinity` as the `percentageCompleted` inside the axios function `onDownloadProgress`. I agree the issue is due to the URL that we are downloading from. In my case I wasn't able to alter the URL so I altered the code to check if infinity. It is't perfect but does allow to show & hide a progress spinner (not a progress bar):

```
  onDownloadProgress(progressEvent) {
    const percentage = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total);
    setProgress(percentage);
    if (percentage === 100 || !percentage.isInFinite) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      }, 400);
    }
  }
```